# javax.persistence @Column mapping of 2 columns of two different table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, javax

I am trying to map an Entity from 3 tables, using @Entity, @Table, @SecondaryTables and @Column annotations as illustrated in the following example.

The Tables are: 
 1. employee (primary)
 2. employee_detail
 3. job_description

```
@Entity    
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")    
@SecondaryTables({    
    @SecondaryTable(name="EMPLOYEE_DETAIL",    
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")),    
    @SecondaryTable(name="JOB_DESCRIPTION",    
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="JD_ID"))    
})
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", table= "EMPLOYEE")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", table = "EMPLOYEE")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", table = "EMPLOYEE")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "BANK_ACCOUNT_NO", table = "EMPLOYEE_DETAIL") 
    private String bankacctnumber;

    @Column(name = "JOB_SUMMARY", table = "JOB_DESCRIPTION") 
    private String jobsummary;

    @Column(name = "     ???      ", table = "     ??        ")
    private String uniqueid;

    //getters and setters for above fields
    ...

}
```

My question is, if I would like to create the field "uniqueid" by concatenating

column "ID" in table "EMPLOYEE" AND column "JOB_CODE" in table "JOB_DESCRIPTION"

This entity corresponds with the following sql query string (I used string builder for clarity):-

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

sql.append("SELECT");
sql.append(" e.FIRST_NAME AS firstname,");
sql.append(" e.LAST_NAME AS lastname,");
sql.append(" d.BANK_ACCT_NUMBER AS bankacctnumber,");
sql.append(" j.JOB_SUMMARY AS jobsummary,");
sql.append(" CONCAT(e.ID,SUBSTR(j.JOB_CODE,3,8)) AS uniqueid"); 
sql.append(" FROM employee e");
sql.append(" LEFT JOIN employee_detail d ON d.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.ID");
sql.append(" LEFT JOIN job_description j ON j.JD_ID = e.JD_ID ");
sql.append(" WHERE e.ID = 1 ");
```

exactly how should the mapping of the columns be done for the field "uniqueid"? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible because JPA is using the mapped columns for reading AND writing. So a column can not be concatenated.

But you can write a simple method in your class that concatenates the fields.

Another possibility to could be a view that uses your SQL statement but then you can only read and now write because the view contains fields of more than one table.

Comment: Thank you Simon! I will try to add a method to concatenate the field.